# Independence of a random variable $X$ from itself

Tags: probability, random-variables

In our lecture on probability, my professor made the comment that "a random variable X is not independent from itself." (Here he was specifically talking about discrete random variables.) I asked him why that was true. (My intuition for two counterexamples are $X \equiv 0$ and $X$ s.t. $$m_X(x) = \begin{cases}1, &\text{ if } x = x_0\\ 0, &\text{ if }x \neq x_0.)\end{cases}$$

In these cases, it seems that $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x_1 , X \leq x_2) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x_1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \leq x_2)$.

My professor's response was, "The independence from or dependence of $X$ on itself depends on the definition of the joint distribution function $m_{X,X}$, which is essentially arbitrary."

Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a random variable is independent of itself if and only if it is a constant, i.e., $X = E[X]$.

Comment: $X \equiv 0$ (or $X \equiv a$ for a constant $a$) is definitely a valid counterexample.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only *events* that are independent of themselves are those with probability either $0$ or $1$.  That follows from the fact that a number is its own square if and only if it's either $0$ or $1$.  The only way a random variable $X$ can be independent of itself is if for every measurable set $A$, either $\Pr(X\in A)=1$ or $\Pr(X\in A)=0$.  That happens if and only if $X$ is essentially constant, meaning there is some value $x_0$ such that $\Pr(X=x_0)=1$.

Comment: In layman's terms, why is a random number not independent of each other?  In a uniform distribution, getting one value does not increase the odds of getting another value.  I guess I am not understanding the concept of independence.

Comment: @confused : The question is about events that are independent of THEMSELVES, not indpendent of EACH OTHER.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $X$ is an event from a sample space S, and suppose that $X$ is independent of itself. This means that $P(X/X)=P(X)$. But by definition,

$$P(X∩X)=P(X)P(X/X)= P(X)P(X)=P(X)^2$$

but $P(X\cap X)=P(X)$, since $X\cap X=X$. Therefore, $P(X)=P(X/X)=P(X)P(X)=P(X)^2$.

This result only can occur when $P(X)=1$ or $P(X)=0$. In conclusion, an event $X$ from a sample space $S$ can be independent of itself only if $P(X)=1$ or $P(X)=0$.