# $X$ and $X^2$ independent, show that there is $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(|X|=c)=1$

Tags: probability-theory

$X$ and $X^2$ independent real valued, random variables, show that there is $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(|X|=c)=1$

I would like to receive a hint on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: For any set $A\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
P(|X|\in A) = P(|X|\in A ; X^2\in A^2) = P(|X|\in A)P(X^2\in A^2) = P(|X|\in A)^2.
$$
Therefore $P(|X|\in A)$ is either zero or 1.

Comment: Sure, if you define $A^2 \mathop{\,:=\,} \{z^2\mid z\in A\}$.

Comment: What does the ";" in $P(|X| \leq x ; X^2 \leq x^2)$ mean to you?

Comment: It's supposed to denote "and".

Answer (score 5):

Intuitive reasoning: $X$ and $X^2$ being independent means that knowing $X$ tells you nothing about $X^2$. This cannot be true if $|X|$ can attain more than one value.

Answer (score 4):

Note that for any $x\in{\bf R}$,
$$
P(|X|\leq x)=P(|X|\leq x,X^2\leq x^2)=P(|X|\leq x)\cdot P(X^2\leq x^2)=P(|X|\leq x)^2.
$$
Using the properties of probability distribution function one can [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/512763/9464) that $|X|$ is constant (almost surely).

Comment: It is more accurate to restrict $x \geq 0$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: the expression is still valid when $x<0$. Also, it is trivial though, one does need to consider the case when $x<0$ since one needs the probability distribution function for $|X|$.

Comment: @Olba12: it means "and".

Comment: What does the "," in $P(|X| \leq x , X^2 \leq x^2)$ mean to you?  A logical and?

Comment: Ohh, wanted to edit my comment to add the "and" but had to make a new one according to the time of editing. Sorry.

Comment: I understand that $x < 0$ is the trivial case, but without removing it, the last equality you wrote is not logically correct. I brought this up for this consideration only. A good solution overall.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: I believe the last equality is correct in the case when $x<0$. For instance $P(|X|<-1)=0$ and trivially one has $P(|X|\leq -1)\cdot P(X^2\leq 1)=0=P(|X|\leq -1)^2$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: The reason I said in the previous comment that the case $x<0$ is trivial is that every term involved in the chain of identities becomes $0$. You are probably concerning the situation that $P(X^2\leq (-1)^2)\neq P(|X|\leq -1)$. However, the last equality itself *is* true and logically correct since both sides are $0$ when $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $a>0$ $$P(X^2\leq a^2\mid X>b)=P(|X|\leq a\mid X>b)=P(|X|\leq a)\space\text{if $b\leq -a$}\\=P(b\leq X\leq a)\space\text{if $-a< b\leq a$}\\=0\space\text{if $b>a$}$$

But since $X^2$ and $X$ are independent $$P(X^2\leq a^2\mid X>b)=P(|X|\leq a)$$

Then if $-a<b\leq a$, $P(-a\leq X<b)=0$. If we choose $b=a$ then we get $P(X=a)>0$

Similarly if $a<0$ we get $P(X=-a)>0$.

Hence $P(|X|=a)>0$ o.w. $P(|X|=x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{a\}$.

Then $P(|X|=a)=1\space\space\space\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

There are two independently useful facts which are being used here:

- if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for any continuous $f,g$;
- if $X$ is independent of itself then it is almost surely a constant.

The proofs are both simple. For the first, we have
$$P(f(X)\in A,g(Y)\in B)=P(X\in f^{-1}(A),Y\in g^{-1}(B))=P(X\in f^{-1}(A))P(Y\in g^{-1}(B))=P(f(X)\in A)P(g(Y)\in B).$$
For the second,
$$P(X\le x)=P(X\le x,X\le x)=P(X\le x)^2,$$
so $P(X\le x)\in\{0,1\}$. This implies $P(X=c)=1$ where $c=\min\{x:P(X\le x)=1\}$.

Using the independence of $|X|$ and $X^2$ is actually a bit redundant, since the proof of this is the same as proving $X^2$ is independent of itself, which implies $X^2=c$ and thus $|X|=\sqrt{c}$ with probability one.