# When is $A \in \mathscr{F}$ independent of itself?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space. When is $A \in \mathscr{F}$ independent of itself?

My "solution" is
$$P(A\cap A)=P(A)P(A)=P(A)^2 ???$$

I am unsure if my work is correct or if I am failing to see the meaning behind this result.

Comment: Can you go a bit further?

Comment: Note that $P(A\cap A)=P(A)$ is always true. When is $x^2=x$?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/512755/9464

Comment: @Jack Got it! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

A set $A$ is independent of itself if and only if it is trivial: namely $P(A)$ is zero or one. This is because $P(A \cap A) = P(A) = P(A)^2$ holds if and only if $P(A)$ is zero or one.