# Intuition of Kolmogorov‘s 0-1 Law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Kolmogorov‘s 0-1 Law seems to say something very intuitive: Tail events of independent objects have probability $0$ or $1$.

At least it should be intuitive - but it is not to me. Why exactly are tail events supposed to have this behaviour? What‘s the intuitive argument?

Answer (score 3):

Intuition is right there in the proof of the theorem. If $A \in \sigma (X_n,X_{n+1},...)$ for every $n$ then $A$ is independent of $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ for every $n$. So what does $A$ depend on? Intuitively it is independent of itself and [only trivial events can be independent of themselves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423860/when-is-a-in-mathscrf-independent-of-itself).

Comment: Thanks. I‘m not sure if this is what I‘m looking for, though. Do you mean that $A$ is pretty much independent of everything, so intuitively, $A$ should also be independent of itself? This last step is not quite intuitive to me. (Yes, I do know the proof of the theorem.)

Comment: Precisely. $A$ is some  event defined in terms of $X_1,X_2,...$ and it is not only independent of each $X_n$ it is also jointly independent of $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ for each $n$. It has to be independent of itself.

Comment: Alright, this is a good explanation, thank you!