# Variance of a multiple of a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, variance

a) Say we have two independent distribution variables $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim Pois(\mu)$. [We know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221078/poisson-distribution-of-sum-of-two-random-independent-variables-x-y#221087) that the sum of the two will be
$$X+Y\sim Pois(\lambda+\mu),$$
and hence the variance will be $Var(X+Y)=\lambda+\mu$.

b) We also know that in general $Var(b\cdot X) = b^2\cdot Var(X)$:
$$ Var(bX) = E(b^2X^2) - E^2(bX) = b^2E(X^2) - b^2E^2(X) = b^2 Var(X) $$

However, if I take the distribution $X + X$, I have two different results for the variance:

a) $X + X \sim Pois(\lambda + \lambda) = Pois(\alpha)$, with $\alpha = 2\lambda$, and hence 
$$Var(X+X) = \alpha = 2\lambda$$
b) $$Var(X+X)=Var(2X)=2^2Var(X)=4\lambda$$

What am I doing wrong? According to my exercise sheet, a) is correct, but then I don't see why b) wouldn't apply.
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Is $X$ independent of itself when you apply the result (a) ?

Comment: According to the master solution of my exercise sheet it seems to be, but then again, it could be a mistake... I am honestly not sure...

Comment: Have a look at this post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512755/independence-of-a-random-variable-x-from-itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ and $X$ are not independent. Hence you cannot apply result (a). In fact,  you have shown that $2X$ is not a poisson random variable as $Var(2X)\neq E(2X)$ as $\lambda>0$.

Comment: I see. Hence there really seems to be an error in my textbook. Thank you very much!