# If $X+Y$ is independent from $X$ and independent from $Y$, then $X+Y$ is deterministic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, fourier-analysis

> Let $X,Y$ be two real random variables such that $X+Y$ is independent from $X$ and also independent from $Y$. Show that $X+Y$ is deterministic

If $X$ and $Y$ have a variance, then we can compute :
$$\mathbb E[(X+Y)^2] = \mathbb E[ X (X+Y)] + \mathbb E[Y(X+Y)] =  \mathbb E[ X ]\mathbb E[X+Y] + \mathbb E[Y]\mathbb E[X+Y] = (\mathbb E[X+Y])^2$$
and therefore $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = 0$ and $X+Y$ is almost surely constant.

In the general case however, I don't see how to prove this. Using the characteristic function $f_X(t) = \mathbb E[e^{itX}]$, I can show that :
$$\forall t,s\in\mathbb R,f_X(t) f_{X+Y}(s) = f_{X+Y}(s+t) f_Y(-t)$$
I am not sure if and how this helps, though.

Comment: Are you assuming $X+Y$ to be independent of $X$ and to be independent of $Y$ or are you assuming that $X+Y$ is independent of $(X,Y)$?

Comment: As Tobios mentioned is not clear from the posting that whether the assumption is $X+Y$ independent of $\sigma(X,Y)$ or $both X+Y$ is idenpendent of $\sigma(X)$ and  $X+Y$ is independent of $\sigma(Y)$. In the later the answer is obvious $X+Y$ is indeoendent form it self this $P[X+Y>c]\in\{0,1\}$ for all $c$ and this $X+Y$ must be a constant. The later is much more complicated.

Comment: I was asking about the harder case. Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notation: I use $Z\perp Y$ to denote that $Z$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, and $\phi_Z(t)=E[\exp(itZ)]$ for the characteristic function of the random variable $Z$.

Assume $X+Y\perp X$ and $X+Y\perp Y$. Then, for all $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$

\begin{align}
\phi_{X+Y}(s+t)\phi_Y(-t)&=E[\exp(i(X+Y)(s+t))\exp(-itY)]\\
&=E[\exp(is(X+Y))\exp(itX)]\\
&=\phi_{X+Y}(s)\phi_X(t)
\end{align}

Similarly,

\begin{align}
\phi_{X+Y}(s+t)\phi_X(-t)&=E[\exp(i(X+Y)(s+t))\exp(-itX)]\\
&=E[\exp(is(X+Y))\exp(itY)]\\
&=\phi_{X+Y}(s)\phi_Y(t)
\end{align}

Hence, for all $s,t$ in a neighborhood of $0$

\begin{align}
\phi_{X+Y}(s+t)&=\phi_{X+Y}(s)\frac{\phi_X(t)}{\phi_Y(-t)}=\phi_{X+Y}(t+s)=\phi_{X+Y}(t)\frac{\phi_X(s)}{\phi_Y(-s)}\\
\phi_{X+Y}(s+t)&=\phi_{X+Y}(s)\frac{\phi_Y(t)}{\phi_X(-t)}=\phi_{X+Y}(t+s)=\phi_{X+Y}(t)\frac{\phi_Y(s)}{\phi_X(-s)}
\end{align}

Thus $\phi_{X+Y}(s)=\frac{\phi_X(s)}{\phi_Y(-s)}=\frac{\phi_Y(s)}{\phi_X(-s)}$ for all $s$ in a neighborhood of $0$. Notice that
$|\phi_{X+Y}(s)|^2=\frac{\phi_X(s)\phi_X(-s)}{\phi_Y(s)\phi_Y(-s)}=1$. Then $|\phi_{X+Y}(s)|=1$ in a neighborhood of $0$; hence $X+Y$ is constant.

The conclusion is based on the following results:

> *Lemma:*
> Suppose $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. If $|\widehat{\mu}(t)|=1$ for some $t\neq0$, then there are $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h>0$ such that $\operatorname{supp}\mu\subset b+h\mathbb{Z}$.

Proof:
Without loss of generality assume $t>0$. Then form some $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$,
\begin{align}
1=e^{-i\theta}\widehat{\mu}(t)=\int \cos(xt-\theta)\,\mu(dx)
\end{align}
Then $x\mapsto\cos(xt-\theta)=1$ $\mu$--a.s.  Hence, $\operatorname{supp}\mu\subset \frac{\theta}{t}+\frac{2\pi}{t}\mathbb{Z}$.

> *Theorem*
> Suppose  $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If
> $|\widehat{\mu}({\bf t})|=1$ in a small neighborhood of ${\bf 0}$,
> then $\mu=\delta_{\boldsymbol{b}}$ for some $\boldsymbol{b}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Proof: By considering the law of each component of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is enough to consider the case $n=1$. For every $t$ in a neighboorhood of $0$, there is a number $b_t$  such that $\operatorname{supp}(\mu)\subset b_t+\frac{2\pi}{|t|}\mathbb{Z}$. If $\mu$ is not a trivial distribution, then there are distinct points $x_1$ and $x_2$ of positive measure $\mu$. It follows that $|x_1-x_2|\geq\frac{2\pi}{|t|}$. This is not possible as $|t|$ can be taken to be very small.

Answer (score 7):

If $S= X+Y$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$, any measurable function of $S$ is independent of any measurable function of $X$ and $Y$. So, $S$ is independent of $f(X,Y) = X+Y$, and so $S$ is independent of itself, [hence almost-surely constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512755/independence-of-a-random-variable-x-from-itself).

EDIT: The original poster has clarified their problem, which is that $X+Y$ is independent of $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ separately, instead of $\sigma(X,Y)$. In the former case, this explanation does not hold.

Comment: (+1) I have added an explanation as to why being independent of itself implies the rv is constant a.s. It is not an immediate fact and I cannot seem to find a link to it. However, it is a nice excercise in measure theory and is an application of the Cantor's Intersection Theorem.

Comment: your posting solves a different problem: $X+Y$ independent of $(X,Y)$, then $X+Y$ constant a.s. This is different from $X+Y$ independent of $X$ and $X+Y$ independent of $Y$ implies $X+Y$ constant. The former problems is trivial, the one the OP is asking is not.

Comment: @Mittens I had posted my explanation before the original poster had made this claraficiation and have edited my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

A small addition @Julius' answer and a slight caution to Solublefish is that the fact that "if $X$ is an r.v. such that $P(X\in A)=0$ or $1$ for each Borel set $A$ implies $X$ is a constant" is not directly apparent. One has to go by Cantor's Intersection Theorem to prove this fact and is infact a nice problem in measure theory. Well, just keep shrinking compact intervals of probability $1$ and you'll get a unique point $x_{0}$ by Cantor's Intersection Theorem to which the distribution of $X$ will give mass $1$. I cannot seem to find a link to this in this site so I'll just write it up myself.

So let $\mu$ be the distribution of $X+Y$ in this case, i.e. $\mu(A)=P((X+Y)\in A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R})$. As $X+Y$ is independent of itself (By Julius') answer.

So now consider $\mu([n,n+1))$ where $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. Then atleast one of these $[n,n+1)$ has to have non-zero measure, i.e. $\mu([n,n+1))\neq 0$ as otherwise $\mu(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{Z}}[n,n+1))=\mu(\Bbb{R})=0$.

So assume $\mu([n,n+1))=1$ . Now if $\mu(\{n\})=1$, then you are done and $X+Y=n$

Otherwise $\mu((n,n+1))=1$.  Now divide $[n,n+1]$ into $[n,n+\frac{1}{2}]$ and $[n+\frac{1}{2},n+1]$ . Again, by the above argument, we will asume that $\mu(\{n+\frac{1}{2}\})=0$ as otherwise the proof is completed automatically.

So atleast one and exactly one of $[n,n+\frac{1}{2}]$ or $[n+\frac{1}{2},n+1]$ must be given mass $1$. Suppose it is $[n,n+\frac{1}{2}]$.

Then again you divide this interval into two parts and carry on the same procedure inductively. If you stop at a finite time, then you have found your constant $c$ which is an end point of one of such interval.

Otherwise, if the process goes on and on, then you have a decreasing sequence of compact intervals $I_{k}$ such that $I_{k}\subseteq I_{k-1}$ and hence by Cantor's Intersection Theorem, you'll find an unique $x_{0}$ such that $\{x_{0}\}=\bigcap_{k}I_{k}$ and

$\mu(\{x_{0}\})=\mu(\bigcap_{k}I_{k})=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^{m}I_{k})=\lim_{m\to\infty}\mu(I_{m})=1$

**NOTE** Using (hyper)cubes instead of intervals, you can see that this result will also be true for $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ valued random variables.

Comment: Surely it is more straightforward to consider the cdf $F(x)=\mathbb{P}(S \leq x)$ to deduce that $S=s$ a.s., where $s=\sup\{x : F(x) = 0\}$? Since $\bigcup_n (-\infty, s-1/n] = (-\infty, s)$ and $\bigcap_n (\infty, s+1/n] = (-\infty, s]$, it follows from standard properties of probability measure that $\mathbb{P}(S=s)=1.$

Comment: @Julius Ah yes ofcourse. I was thinking more in terms of $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ which led me approach like this.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron: The OP's assumption are $X+Y$ independent from $X$ and $X+Y$ independent from $Y$. In which case the answer is more subtle for the assumption $X+Y$ is indepondent form $\sigma(X,Y)$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron  The method generalises to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by considering each coordinate individually.

Comment: @Mittens I see. I did not read the comments fully. But in anycase, the proof will go by showing $X+Y$ is independent of itself. My so called "answer" only serves to show the details which allows one to conclude such an rv is constant.

Comment: Once one shows that $X+Y$ is independent of it self, sure it is trivial to show $X+Y$ constant a.s; but the difficult part remains, is $X+Y$, under the hypothesis of the OP, independent of itself?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron: Using Fourier transform a short proof of your statement follows (in $\mathbb{R}^n$: If $X$ independent of $X$ then $\phi_X(s+t)=E[e^{iXt}e^{iXs}]=E[e^{iXt}e^{iXs}]=\phi_X(t)\phi_X(s)$. Hence $1=\phi_X(0)=\phi_X(t)\phi_X(-t)=|\phi_X(t)|^2$, that is $|\phi_X(t)|=1$ for all $t$. Consequently, $X$ is constant almost surely (Theorem in my posting)