# If $E(XY)=E(X) \cdot E(Y)$, why is not $E(X^2)=[E(X)^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

My book states that the expected value of the product of two independent random variables equal the product of their expected values. Why cannot one use this to give the following?

$$E(X \cdot X) = E(X) \cdot E(X) = [E(X)]^2$$

Of course, this is incorrect, as if this were true the variance would always be 0.

Comment: "the product of two **independent** random variables equal the product of their expected values." You seem to have overlooked that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $X$ is not independent of itself, consider $X$ to be the value of a coin flip: $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=1/2$.

Recall that $X$ and $Y$ are independent means for any (nice enough) sets $A,B\in\mathbb{R}$, $P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$.

But $P(X=1,X=0)=0\neq 1/4=P(X=1)P(X=0).$

Answer (score 8):

Because $X$ and $X$ are not independent.

For more info, [see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149723/why-is-the-expected-value-ex2-neq-ex2) that asks something very similar if not the same.