# Need some help figuring out $E(X^2)$

Tags: statistics

This is my first question and I hate making this a new question, as I found an answer to a similar question, but it's not quite clear and I don't have enough rep to leave a comment asking for more info.

So I got quite stumped trying to figure out $E(X^2)$ in statistics.
I found this answer while googling:
--Quote--
Actually, if $EX=\mu$ and $E(X-\mu)^2=\sigma^2$

$$
EX^2 = E[X-\mu+\mu]^2=\\
=E(X-\mu)^2-2E[(X-\mu)\mu]+E(\mu^2)=\\=\sigma^2-2\mu E(X-\mu)+\mu^2=\\
=\sigma^2+\mu^2
$$

So $EX^2 =\sigma^2+\mu^2$, no matter the distribution, and $EX^2\ne(EX)^2$ unless the variance equals zero.
--End quote--
Here's a link to said answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/737227/693253

Now, if that answer is correct it certainly solves most of my problems but I'm having trouble figuring out this step:
$$
\sigma^2-2\mu E(X-\mu)+\mu^2=\\
=\sigma^2+\mu^2
$$
I don't get how he gets rid of the $-2\mu E(X-\mu)$

I guess the question is both "is this answer correct?" and some help figuring out that step, if it is.
If it's not correct, I'd like some help figuring out $E(X^2)$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

$\mathbb E(X) = \mu$ so $\mathbb E(X-\mu) = 0$.
This is because:

1. Expected value is linear.
2. Expected value of a constant is that constant.

Comment: right! $E(X-\mu)=EX-\mu=\mu-\mu=0$